# Next.js 13.4 doesn't update UI when saving changes

Tags: next.js, hot-reload

Nextjs 13.4 doesn't hot reload. I'm using Nexjs13.4 along with TailwindCSS. While trying to update something in codebase. It doesn't update UI instantly.

Actually it works after restarting the server. Can anyone help me how to get rid of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean JSX component doesn't hot reload?

Comment: Yes, after updating something on JSX it doesn't update the UI instantly.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of issues at play.

**1.** Initially, make sure you've **enabled Hot Reload** **in** Visual Studio Code or whichever **IDE** you're using.

**2.** Ensure that you are using the **latest version of Node.js.**
You can verify this by running `node -v`. If it shows a version lower than **20.6**, consider **updating Node.js** to the newest version available.

**3.** In your **tailwind.config.ts**, verify that you've included the correct folder structure in your content section. Depending on your specific folder setup, it may look something like:

```
content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
```

**4.** Insert a `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` tag into your HTML header.

Comment: Looks like AI-generated answer.

Comment: It is not. Those are the step i went through to fix my hot reload with the next 13 - it worked.

Comment: Upgrading to Node version 21 helped a lot. Thank you.